# jQuery / javascript - correcting input min and max int not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="eingangstuer_hoehe" min="70" max="200">
```

And this is the jQuery/javascript:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = $this.val();
        var max = $this.attr("max");
        var min = $this.attr("min");


        if(val > min || val < max)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (val > max){
                e.preventDefault();
                $this.val(max);
            }

            if (val < min)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $this.val(min);
            }
        }
});
```

Typing `1` or `2` will not change anything. Typing `3` - `69` will work how it supposed to. Typing everything above `199` (yes also `200`) will change the value to `70`..

It also won't change the values above `600`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the condition as shown in the code snippet below.

Also You're compering string and not numbers.
try parsing the values to integer with parseInt

your code should look like this:

```
    $("input").change(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = parseInt($this.val());
        var max = parseInt($this.attr("max"));
        var min = parseInt($this.attr("min"));

        if(val < min || val > max){
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(max);
        }
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Wrong condition found. Change `if(val > min || val < max)` to `if(val >= min && val <= max)`